# Combining foreach statements in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, foreach

I have a Wordpress website and I have a gallery listed with an image and url for each item. However I can't seem to combine the foreach statements. I always get errors. I know I am close, I think I just need to re-arrange things a bit. Thank you!

```
<?php 
foreach($latest_projects as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
//get image
$recent_project_thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'recent-work');

foreach ($categories as $cat ) :
//get image
$categories = get_terms('gallery_cats');
?> 

<li><a href="https://website.com/<?php echo $cat->slug; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $recent_project_thumb[0]; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" width="162" height="100" class="imgstyle" /></a></li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you only have one closing foreach statement. Other than that the code looks good. I would do a little better indenting so that you can see.

```
<?php 
foreach($latest_projects as $post) : //begin post foreach
    setup_postdata($post);

    //get image
    $recent_project_thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'recent-work');

    foreach ($categories as $cat ) : //begin categories foreach
        //get image
        $categories = get_terms('gallery_cats');
?> 

        <li>
            <a href="https://website.com/<?php echo $cat->slug; ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $recent_project_thumb[0]; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" width="162" height="100" class="imgstyle" />
            </a>
        </li>

    <?php endforeach; ?> //end categories foreach
<?php endforeach; ?> //end post foreach
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I don't want to have 2 loops, I actually want to combine them somehow that's why I have only put one <?php endforeach; ?> statement at the end. I am also getting an error at foreach ($categories as $cat ) Thanks for your help!